# Limit of sin(1/n)*n

Tags: limits

My Maple input `limit(sin(1/n)*n,n=infinity);` says 1.

I don't understand why
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \cdot n = 1
$$

I know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 0$, so it kind of says "0 * infinity = 1".

Have I overlooked some rewriting of $\sin(1/n) n$?

Comment: This is equivalent to [this standard limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

Comment: Yes. 0*infinity(limit) can equal to one. Remind limit of $\dfrac{1}{n}.n$

Comment: @isuramanchanayake That's a misleading statement.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli why? did my edit corrected it?

Answer (score 7):

Make a change of variables $x={1\over n}$ so that $x\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, then use $\lim_{x\to 0} {\sin x\over x}=1$.

Comment: It should be noted that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1$ is a standard limit and is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

Answer (score 3):

$$n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \cdot n = \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{\sin n}{n}=1$$

Comment: You nailed it man. This is as simple as it gets. good use of basics.

Comment: $n\to 0$ doesnot mean.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow n$ so $\frac{1}{\infty} \rightarrow 0$

Comment: you are right if you use for example $x=\frac{1}{n}$, but for natural number we just define limit $n\to\infty$

Comment: I didt write $\frac{1}{n}=n$ but $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow n$

Answer (score 1):

Because $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1,$$which can most easily seen by the Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ about $0,$ $$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040} + \dots.$$ Taking $x$ as $1/n$ reveals the deep equivalence.